# Minimum context slot has not been reached when trying to send a transaction

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, blockhash

I'm trying to submit a transaction from a frontend application (React, `@solana/web3.js`), but every now and then when I try to submit a transaction, it fails with this error message:

```
 err: SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Minimum context slot has not been reached
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (...)
```

I can try clicking again and it usually works on the second try, but is there a way to reliably avoid this error? My transaction submission code looks like this:

```
      try {
        const {
          context: { slot: minContextSlot },
          value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight },
        } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext("finalized");
    
        const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction, {
          minContextSlot,
          skipPreflight: true,
        });

        const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction({
          signature: signature,
          blockhash,
          lastValidBlockHeight,
          minContextSlot,
        });
        ...
    } catch (error) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's likely happening is that you're using a load-balanced RPC endpoint, like the public ones, and you're hitting different backends on different requests, which haven't all reached the same slot.

For example, the first time, you hit a "faster" node, which is at slot 101, and you get a `minContextSlot` of 101. When you send the transaction, you're requiring that the node has reached at least `minContexSlot`, but the next request may reach a node which is only at slot 100, and so rejects the transaction.

You could change your connection to always hit the same node by provisioning your own, or reduce `minContextSlot` if your app can tolerate it. For example, if you're ok with using an endpoint that's 4 slots off, you can pass in `minContextSlot - 4` to `sendTransaction` and `confirmTransaction`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! It's annoying that it wasn't even a public node, but a paid one..